Tough chuck steak in slow cooker
Recipe 2.5kg chuck steak 8-10 hours on low. Used 900g cooked for 8 hours. Meat was very tough, should cooking time have beeb reduced?
No problem with chuck steak before but first time in small slow cooker.

We'd need to know the recipe and preparation to judge whether it was cooked appropriately for that cut. For instance was the meat submerged in the cooking liquid, was it cut into chunks or one big lump, how much fat was on the meat etc.

also appreciated if you write the details in the body of the question, keep the title shorter

Yes, generally speaking, smaller cuts or portions lead to reduced cooking time.
However, it is not as simple as dividing the time by the same ratio as the weight of the meat. It also depends on the thickness, since the heat takes a certain time to get into the center.
I.e. if a thick carrot takes 10 minutes to cook, a leaner carrot will take less, but half of that big carrot will still take about the same. Ten leaner carrots, while technically heavier in total, will still not take 10 minutes.
To get the right time for your specific steak, you’ll either have to experiment or find a more precise recipe for that size.

A steak in a slow cooker, cooking for several hours, will spend virtually all its time at nearly 100 Celsius. The thickness doesn’t significantly affect that.
